# How to post a fake entry in "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" with customized id

Tags: angular, http, http-post

Sirs, I just want to ask on how to post a fake entry "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" api with customized id, say, id = 123. because when i post, it automatically post "101" as an id. This is using Angular by the way. Thanks

i have this code, but not sure if this is the correct way:

```
  onSubmit() {
    const list = {
      id: this.id,
      title: this.title,
      body: this.body
    }
    this.sample.samplefunc(list).subscribe(list => {
      list.id = 123
      this.lists.push(list)
    })
  }
```

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible. the example code [jsonplaceholder provides](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#creating-a-resource) clearly indicates that the id is not one of the fields that can be set. I imagine that this is intended to simulate ids being generated server side, which is how most REST APIs work. Are you meaning to set the `user_id` instead?

Comment: hi, im not sure. cos i have to do "put request" on this http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/456, so i thought it was an id. thanks

Comment: That link returns a 404... If you are using the http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com url and not you own installation, posts you create won't be saved so this won't help you with subsequent put requests anyway

Comment: so you think that it was userId? may i know how to to do that? thanks. i appreciate it.

Comment: By default, user ids for http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com only go up to 10 so, no. You might want to ask whoever gave you this homework assignment, perhaps getting a 404 is what they want

Comment: so in jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/234, the "234" is the id right? and cannot be created?

Comment: That's right yeah.